# Pop-up windows asking the user for input/save his work (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, dialog

I am writing a program and I need some help. It starts by asking this question:

`A = questdlg('What would you like to do?','Artificial Neural Network',...
     'Train','Test','Exit','Exit');`

Then depending what the use chooses it asks certain questions and do certain things

`if strcmp (A,'Train')

```
 B = questdlg ('Would you like to create a new network or add to the already trained data?',...
     '!','Create','Add','Exit','Exit');

 if strcmp (B, 'Create')
     if strcmp (B, 'Create')

     %add as many text file as he wants to - need to figure out how I
     %can extract the data from them though
     [fname,dirpath]=uigetfile ('*.txt','Select a txt file','MultiSelect',...
         'on');

 elseif strcmp(B,'Add')

     %choose what type is it
     D = listdlg('PromptString','What colour is it?',...
            'SelectionMode','single', 'ListString',...
            {'Strawberry','Orange',...
            'Chocolate','Banana','Rose'}, 'Name','Select Ice Cream',...
            'ListSize',[230 130]);

        %and then whatever choise he chooses it will feed it to the main 
        %function. For example if he chooses Orange then it will go the
        %second part of the training, if it chooses Rose and the fifth
        %one and so on.  

 else strcmp(B,'Exit')
     disp('Exit')

 end
```

So the thing I want help with is:

1. How can the user when he imports the txt files in Matlab use them in order to run the program? and
2. How can the user add more choices at the `listdlg` and when it will choose a choice then automatically it will go to the corresponding step of the code?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!! :)

PS: Sorry for the long post!

Answer (score 2):

with uigetfile etc. you only get the filename and path. But to get the data you have to load the file:

For mat-files use:

[TMW: load mat-files](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/load.html)

For other files use:

[TMW: load data from file](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html)

Answer (score 1):

To open a file in MATLAB, you can use [uigetfile](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html). To save a file, you can use [uiputfile](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiputfile.html). This will open up standard file dialog boxex for opening and saving files. The result would be a cell array, and then use [textscan](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to read the data from the individual files.

You should [switch-case](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html). On selecting one of the choices, you can train the neural network accordingly. The training preferably should be written in separate m files or different subfunctions for readability.

Comment: thank you!I have already changed the `uigetdir` with the `uigetfile` and now I have also used the `uiputfile`. The only problem I have now is when I open my text files using `[fname,dirpath]=uigetfile ('*.txt','Select a txt file','MultiSelect','on');` I get a cell instead of the actual data that is in the text files. Any idea how can I get the actual data and not only the name of the files?

Comment: You could [textread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textread.html) for each of the files. This will get data from each of the files. Since it is a cell, use [cellfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), to read data from each of the text files.

Comment: sorry, but this is wrong: from TMW: uigetfile-> Successful execution of uigetfile does not open a file; it only returns the name of an existing file that you identify.

Comment: hm..but if I can't use the `uigetfile` then how can the user add the files he wants?

Comment: @LuciusDomitiusAhenobarbus: Yes, but you do get the name of the files you want to open.

Comment: @LuciusDomitiusAhenobarbus: I dont think you saw the question before the first edit. If you look at Chrysovalando's first comment, he added the uigetfile once I answered.

Comment: I see... but still, uigetfile does not open a file

Comment: Since, its a text file, I added a comment for using textread. The cellarray ouput can processed using textread.

Comment: imho the answer to the question should not be given in the comment but in the answer... if I would just read the answer I would get the wrong info. So I would suggest to edit the answer

Comment: so do you reckon that the best way to deal with it is by using textread? (i am a bit confused right now)

Comment: No! take a look at my post. In addition take a look at the docs of TMW:Note:   textread is not recommended. Use textscan instead. [TMW: textread](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/textread.html)

Comment: Thanks @LuciusDomitiusAhenobarbus for pointing that out. I have edited my answer with your suggestions.